# sqlite3_prepare_v2() - "no such table"

Tags: c, sqlite

I've got a local DB that I'm trying to open to read from on a little ARM device. I've gone about crafting the beginnings of an SQLite3 sub-API specifically for usage on this device, but I'm running into a strange problem now.

Upon executing `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` on the statement `"select * from passback where serial = ? and prod_ndx = ?"` on a database that has been successfully opened (with `sqlite3_open_v2()`, so there are no phantom databases because of a typo'd filename) and `integrity_check()`'d, I receive the error of `"no such table: passback"`.

Again, I know for certain the table exists in the database which was opened. What's sillier, is that the exact same function which calls `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` (and subsequent binds, etc) works to read/write to/from at least one other database on this machine.

What might be going on here?

Comment: What flags are you using with `sqlite3_open_v2()`? Do you forbid it to create a new database for your typo'd filename?

Comment: `sqlite3_open_v2(db_filename, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);`

Comment: How do you know that the table exists?

Comment: I test the return of `sqlite3_open_v2()` later in the code.

Comment: But `sqlite3_open_v2()` does not check whether a table exists.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry. I misread your question as asking if I verify whether the database exists. The table isn't verified to exist outside of `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` returning erroneously. However, needless to say, I've made bloody sure the table exists. As in, logging string literals for all the commands passed (opening, etc) and ran them myself on the shell and seen success, as well as `sqlite3 (database) 'select * from sqlite_master;'`.

Comment: And you run the `sqlite3` shell on the device? With the same complete file name?

Comment: Right. The `#define`'s I'm using in C expand out to the entire file name, path included. Those are the printed logs I used to run the `sqlite3` shell command and see it work.